# MS SQL reporting from busy table

Tags: sql-server, performance, reporting

I've tried to search for some ideas but can't find anything that's very suitable for my scenario.

I have a table which I write and updata data to from multiple sites, maybe a row per second for specific hours of the day and on average having around 50k records added daily. Seperate to this, I have dashboards where people can query this data but some of the queries may be quite complex and take a number of seconds to complete.

- I can't afford my write/updates to slow down
- Although the dashboards don't need to be real time, it would be a bonus

Im hosting on Azure DB S2. What options are available?

Current idea is to use an 'active' table for writes/updates and flush the data to the full table every x min. My only concern is that I have a seeded bigint as a PK on the main table and because I also save other data linked to this, I'd have problems linking to this id until I commit to the main table. An option would be to reseed the active table and set identity insert off on the main table to populate it myself but I'm not 100% happy with this.

Just looking for suggestions until I go ahead with my current idea! Thanks

Comment: That's practically what [snapshot isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) was invented for: readers that don't block writers. With `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`, it can be made the default isolation level so that even writers don't block writers (but you need a retry policy for failed updates instead).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the pointer, I haven't tried this before. I'm assuming it is set at a database rather than table level? Might give it a try and see how it goes on a test db, any potential issues I should look out for?

Comment: Enabling snapshot isolation (`ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION`) is a database-level option, choosing to use it is a per-transaction setting. The biggest impact is on application logic: a query may fail with an update conflict, requiring retries (where before they would just block). The second-biggest impact is [increased I/O, especially for tempdb](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2008/03/29/overhead-of-row-versioning/). You should test whether the trade-off is worth it (snapshot isolation would not also require keeping redundant copies to avoid blocking).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!